# Remove duplicated cell content using python?

Tags: python, pandas

I filter the duplicates, got duplicate on the same row and join items by comma and with this below code, don't really understand why the `Join_Dup` column is replicated?

```
dd = sales_all[sales_all['Order ID'].duplicated(keep=False)]
dd['Join_Dup'] = dd.groupby('Order ID')['Product'].transform(lambda x: ','.join(x))
print(dd.head())

dd = dd[['Order ID','Join_Dup']].drop_duplicates()
dd




     Order ID                                           Join_Dup
0        176558  USB-C Charging Cable,USB-C Charging Cable,USB-...
2        176559  Bose SoundSport Headphones,Bose SoundSport Hea...
3        176560  Google Phone,Wired Headphones,Google Phone,Wir...
5        176561  Wired Headphones,Wired Headphones,Wired Headph...
...         ...                                                ...
186846   259354          iPhone,iPhone,iPhone,iPhone,iPhone,iPhone
186847   259355          iPhone,iPhone,iPhone,iPhone,iPhone,iPhone
186848   259356  34in Ultrawide Monitor,34in Ultrawide Monitor,...
186849   259357  USB-C Charging Cable,USB-C Charging Cable,USB-...

[178437 rows x 2 columns]
```

I need to remove the duplicates from the cell in each row, can some please help.

Comment: because if no parameter in `drop_duplicates` it means remove duplicates by all columns together, so here `259354` and `259355` are different, so not removed. Maybe you want `dd.groupby('Order ID')['Product'].agg(lambda x: ','.join(x)).reset_index(name='Join_Dup')`

Comment: or `dd[['Order ID','Join_Dup']].drop_duplicates(subset=['Order ID'])` instead `dd[['Order ID','Join_Dup']].drop_duplicates()` in your solution

Comment: Since you found duplicates you can use a for loop and delete all those rows eg:               ```for i in dataframe.index: dataframe = dataframe.drop([i], axis=0)``` and after that to reset it's index you can use this ```dataframe.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)```

Comment: hi there, did any of the answers help?

Answer (score 0):

*Edit* disregard the second part of the answer. I will delete that portion if it ends up not being useful.

So you comment you want unique product strings for each Order ID. You can get that in a single step:

```
dd = (
    sales_all.groupby(['Order ID', 'Product'])['some_other_column']
        .size().rename('quantity').reset_index()
    )
```

Now you have unique rows of OrderID/Product with the count of repeated products (or quantity, as in a regular invoice). You can work with that or you can groupby to form a list of products:

```
orders = dd.groupby('Order ID').Product.apply(list)
```

**---apply vs transform---**

Please note that if you use `.transform` as in your question you will invariably get a result with the same shape as the dataframe/series being grouped (i.e. grouping will be reversed and you will end up with the same number of rows, thus creating duplicates). The function `.apply` will pass the groups of your groupby to the same function, any function, but will not broadcast back to the original shape (it will return only one row per group).

---

### Old Answer

So you are removing ALL `Oder ID`s that appear in multiple rows (if ID 14 appears in two rows you discard both rows). This makes the groupby in the next line redundant, as every grouped ID will have just one line.

Ok, now that's out of the way. Then presumably each row in `Product` contains a list which you are joining with a lambda. This step would be a little faster with a pandas native function.

```
dd['Join_Dup'] = dd.Product.str.join(', ')
# perhaps choose a better name for the column, once you remove duplicates it will not mean much (does 'Join_Products' work?)
```

Now to handle duplicates. You didn't actually need to join in the last step if all you wanted was to remove dups. Pandas can handle lists as well. But the part you were missing is the `subset` attribute.

```
dd = dd[['Order ID', 'Join_Dup']].drop_duplicates(subset='Join_Dup')
```

Comment: The idea was to find complimentary products with the same Product ID  and put them together on the same row.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, let's try to prevent the duplicates in the groupby transform statement:

```
dd['Join_No_Dup'] = dd.groupby('Order ID')['Product'].transform(lambda x: ','.join(set(x)))
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, found a solution that works.

Comment: #Counting unique pairs.
from itertools import combinations
from collections import Counter

count = Counter()
for row in dd['Join_Dup']:#get each row item
    row_list = row.split(',')#get the sub_list
    count.update(Counter(combinations(row_list,2)))


for key, value in count.most_common(10):
    print(key , value)